# Min Max slider to form

Tags: php, sql, forms, slider, jquery-slider

I presently have a search module that submits as a regular html form. In it, I currently fetch an absolute minimum and maximum value for products, for example 50 and 2500.
Now I need to build a slider with two buttons (to select a range) and when the form is submitted, both these user-selected values need to be sent, preferrably as two different variables. I am not familiar with how to do such a thing, any ideas?

Thank you!

Edit: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/

This format would be ideal, however I was not able to even implement the slider, let alone send 2 values with it.
If someone can help with implementation of the above slider, or suggest a different slider method it would be very helpful.

Comment: You should probably change your question to target the issue you had with the jQuery slider.

Comment: Aren't we already having a discussion on this here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7406717/701451

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why weren't you able to implement the jQuery UI slider? Here are the steps I take to including jQueryUI plugins.

1. Link to jQuery
2. Link to jQueryUI
3. Link jQueryUI stylesheet
4. Create HTML

div id="slider">

5 . Create JS

```
$(function(){  
     $('#slider').slider({  
          min: 50,  
          max: 2500
     });     
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/aHFwP/